# How to create plotly stacked bar chart with lines connecting the bars at corners

Tags: python, plotly, stacked-chart

I'm trying to create a stacked bar chart with lines connecting the corners of the bars, like in the image provided (the dashed black lines between the bars). I'm doing this with plotly offline in Spyder.
I also want to display percentage change on those (dashed) lines.

What I want:
[image: Example of stacked bar chart with connecting lines]

Code I have so far:

```
import plotly
import plotly.offline as offline
import plotly.plotly as py 
import plotly.graph_objs as go

trace1 = go.Bar(
    x=['(M)', '(DM)', '(RM)'],
    y=[8.12, 7.3, 8.14],
    name='travel'
    )
trace2 = go.Bar(
    x=['(M)', '(DM)', '(RM)'],
    y=[24.2, 23.2, 23],
    name='service'
    )
trace3 = go.Bar(
    x=['(M)', '(DM)', '(RM)'],
    y = [6.7, 5.7, 5.6],
    name='utility'
    )
trace4 = go.Scatter(
    x=['(M)', '(DM)', '(RM)'],
    y=[39.02, 36.2, 36.74],
    )
data=[trace1, trace2, trace3, trace4]
layout= go.Layout(
    barmode= 'stack',
    title='Realization: 0, 0',
    xaxis=dict(title='Model'),
    yaxis=dict(title='Time (minutes)')
    )
fig= go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
offline.plot(fig, image='png', filename='stacked-bar')
```

And it produces this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but for ordinal data. Maybe you can build on that:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.offline import plot

width = [0.5 for i in x]

x = [1, 2, 4, 5]
y_dict = {'A': [20, 14, 23, 5],
          'B': [12, 18, 29, 8],
          'C': [18, 10, 5, 2]}

data = [go.Bar(name=key, x=x, y=y_dict[key], width=width) for key in y_dict]
layout = go.Layout(barmode= 'stack')

fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)

for i in range(len(x)-1):
    for j, _ in enumerate(y_dict):
        x1 = x[i]
        x2 = x[i+1]

        y1 = 0
        y2 = 0
        for key in list(y_dict.keys())[:j+1]:
            y1 += y_dict[key][i]
            y2 += y_dict[key][i+1]

        fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
            x=[x1+width[0]/2, x2-width[0]/2],
            y=[y1, y2],
            mode="lines",
            showlegend=False,
            line={'dash': 'dash', 'color': "#000000"}
        ))

plot(fig)
```

[image]